# Parsing new Date in JSON

Tags: iphone, regex, xcode, json

I am making a request for data and parsing it in JSON format however I do get errors because it returns timestamps in the javascript form new Date(1500000). How do I go about fixing this issue.
I thought of using regex to put quotes around the new Date(0000000) but it doesn't seem to work. I am using RegexKitLite and SBJSON. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can you provide some code please? E.g. the code you tried already.

Comment: so this is an example code I am using to parse the string resultstring which contains the resulting JSON:

    [resultString replaceOccurrencesOfRegex:@"new Date((.+?))," withString:@"\"\"," range:NSMakeRange(0, [resultString length])];

I am using the regexkitlite to replace the string but i am not very familiar with regex.

Comment: You will probably have more luck getting an answer if you would actually accept the answers you get on other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use;

```
value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
```

where value is your "Date(1500000)" string.